# Webscraping using python for a webpage having "Mehr Anseigen" i.e(eng: Show more)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape a web page and get a few details into an excel or CSV. But unable to get everything since the page is having `Mehr Anzeigen` which is 'Show more' in German.

URL: [https://www.gelbeseiten.de/suche/architekturb%c3%bcros/aachen?umkreis=21000](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

``` From the above ``URL`` I would like to extract: ```

`<h2> class='Title',`

`<address> class= 'mod-AdresseKompakt'`

`<adress> class= 'nbr'`

`. .`

`and so on.`

**Pretty much I would like to load everything automatically (*clicking 'show more' for 30 times is difficult*) and extract all details from the completely loaded website.**

I have read some available threads in Stack-Overflow and some blogs, but each one is different for different websites.

Any help would be great!!

*Python*: I know Python up to some extent, but noob in HTML, and JS.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


path_to_chromedriver = '/Users/kuk/Desktop/chromedriver' # change path as needed
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)

url = 'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/suche/architekturb%c3%bcros/aachen?umkreis=21000'
browser.get(url)


h2 = browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'h2')
for item in h2:  
print(item.text)
```

Comment: what do you want from the "Mehr Anzeigen" pages? title, address and number [as well as email and website] can be gotten from `url` itself...

Comment: Yes, I need email, phonenumber and website as well

Sorry, can you please explain how can I get them for all 324 entries in the page?
I didn't understand what do you mean "can be gotten from `url` "

Any sample code would be helpful.

Comment: sorry, I mixed it up with the "Mehr Details" button...I've posted a potential solution that uses BeautifulSoup, because I already had a selenium+bs4 scraper function as well as one very similar to the one in the answer for getting details from bs4 tags by css selectors, so that was simpler for me; but if you want/need, I can also add a solution that just uses selenium

Comment: That's really impressive solution, and thanks for putting your time and efforts.
Could you please also share the solution with only Selenium, it will be useful in other cases.

Comment: @Kuladeep- I've added an edit to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have [a function (`linkToSoup_selenium`)](https://gist.github.com/Driftr95/cbae6710c134df708f44ade8503f6638#file-linktosoup_selenium-py) that can click through the button a set number of times and then scrape the page

```py
# import pandas # for saving as table
# from linkToSoup_selenium import * ## OR PASTE HERE

cfList = (
    ['//div[@id="cmpbox"]//span[@id="cmpbntyestxt"]'] # "Akzeptieren" - for cookies, I think
    + ['//a[@id="mod-LoadMore--button"]']*30 # click LoadMore 30x
)

soup = linkToSoup_selenium(
     'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/suche/architekturb%c3%bcros/aachen?umkreis=21000'
    , ecx='//article[327]' # wait for listing #327 to load
    , clickFirst=cfList  # cookies + 30xLoadMore
    , strictMode=False # (is False by default but) do NOT set as True 
)
```

(You can either save it as a file and import or paste it at the beginning of your code.) Through the `clickFirst` parameter [a list of xpaths of elements to click], add the [XPath](https://devhints.io/xpath) of "Mehr Anzeigen" as many times as you want to click (it's better to overestimate, since it will only print an error message if it can't click, but since it's inside an isolated `try` block, the rest of program will continue - that's why `strictMode=False` is important here).

---

And then, to get the details, you can define a function as below <sub>(or copy [the full version](https://pastebin.com/BpjZSQPi))</sub>

```py
def getListingDetails(lSoup, refDict):
    detList = {}
    for k, (sel, attr, altr) in refDict.items():
        s = lSoup.select_one(sel)
        if s is None: detVal = None
        elif attr == '': detVal = s.get_text(' ', strip=True)
        else: detVal = s.get(attr)

        if detVal is None or type(altr) != list: altr = [] 
        for a, v in altr:
            if a == 'word1': detVal = detVal.split(v)[0]
            elif a == 'replace': detVal = detVal.replace(v[0], '', v[1]) 

        detList[k] = detVal
    return detList
```

as well as a dictionary of [selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) for each detail

```py
selRef = {
    'Title': ('h2[data-wipe-name="Titel"]', '', ''),
    'Branch': ('p.mod-Treffer--besteBranche', '', ''),
    'Address': ('p[data-wipe-name="Adresse"]', '', ''),
    'Contact': ('p[data-wipe-name="Kontaktdaten"]', '', ''),
    'Website': ('a.contains-icon-homepage[href]', 'href', ''),
    'Email': ('a.contains-icon-email[href^="mailto:"]', 'href', [
        ('replace', ('mailto:', 1)), ('word1', '?')
    ]), 'DetailsPage': ('a.contains-icon-details[href]', 'href', '')
}
```

---

Then, you can simply use list comprehension with `getListingDetails` [from above] and `select`, and then save with `pandas`

```py
if soup:
    lDets = [
        getListingDetails(a, selRef)
        for a in soup.select('article[id^="treffer_"]')
    ]

    pandas.DataFrame(lDets).to_csv('listingDetails.csv', index=False) # save
```

(`lDets` is a list of dictionaries in the same format as `selRef` but with details of the ads instead of selectors.)

The resulting CSV looks like [image: Output CSV]

---

---

#### [EDIT] Selenium without BeautifulSoup

First, to clear the cookies popup and then repeatedly load more without the function,

```py
ac_xpath = '//div[@id="cmpbox"]//span[@id="cmpbntyestxt"]'
WebDriverWait(browser, 25).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, ac_xpath)))
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, ac_xpath).click()

loadMore_xpath = '//a[@id="mod-LoadMore--button"]'
loadMore_maxClicks = 50
for lm_clickCt in range(loadMore_maxClicks):
    print('', end=f'\rClicked "Mehr Anzeigen" {lm_clickCt} times')

    WebDriverWait(browser, 25).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, loadMore_xpath)))
    loadMore_btn = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, loadMore_xpath)
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", loadMore_btn[0])

    if not loadMore_btn: break
    loadMore_btn[0].click()
print('')
```

It will stop trying to load more once the button disappears, or after clicking a maximum number of time (50 as it is); if you don't want to set a maximum, use `while True` instead of `for lm_clickCt in range(loadMore_maxClicks)`, but the button stops working for me sometimes (even when I'm using the browser directly) and I didn't want the program to hang due to an infinite loop.

For extracting details, `selRef` can remain as is but `getListingDetails` will need some adjustments:

```py
# def getListingDetails(lSoup, refDict): # becomes 
def getListingDetails(listingEl, refDict):
```

```py
        # s = lSoup.select_one(sel) # becomes 
        s = listingEl.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel)
```

```py
            # detVal = s.get_text(' ', strip=True) # becomes 
            detVal = s[0].get_attribute('innerText').strip()
```

```py
            # detVal = s.get(attr) # becomes 
            detVal = s[0].get_attribute(attr)
```

and creating `lDets` will also be altered a little

```py
lDets = [
    getListingDetails(a, selRef) for a in
    browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'article[id^="treffer_"]')
]
```